# Do I need a mysql database to upload images used temporarily?

Tags: php, html, mysql, file-upload

On my website I would like to have the possibility of uploading an image, modifying it and printing. I won't be using the images later on, it's important for me to have them available until leaving the "print" page.

Do I need to create a database in order to store the images or is there any other (more simple) way of achieving this? Can you store such things in RAM (excuse my noob question)?

Basically I need to upload the image, display it on the screen, play with it and print it.

Comment: What's wrong with just storing it directly on the file system?

Comment: No, you don't really need a database to upload an image, well, unless you want to store the image paths and any other details like the owner, etc. Simply upload them to a directory (e.g images)

Comment: You don't need a database to store images, you can upload them to a temporary folder and just store the path into a variable.

Comment: All right, thank you, I'm happy to hear that. I've used file uploading only once before (with database then), hence the question.

Comment: You could achieve it by letting a cronjob run and check for the date created timestamp of the file and unlink any that are expired. But the most easy way would be with a database that's for sure.

Comment: I made it the way @gbestard suggested and it works perfectly :) No need for a database at all in this case.

Comment: If all of your changes occur on the client-side, then no, you don't need to store it anywhere. If, however, the changes will be made through a series of PHP pages, then some type of storage of the file name would be good. I'd recommend moving it to a temporary folder, saving the file name as a cookie or session value, and deleting both the session/cookie value as well as the image once they go to "print.php"

Answer (score 0):

Alternativly:

When a user enters the page and uploads an image, create a new folder for this user only and store the relative path in a cookie. This way you could grab the users folder at any time no matter what the user is doing (leaving, coming back, reloading etc.).

**Appended according to the comments**
Dont use plain-text values (I bet nobody knew this when using cookies).

Comment: And this way the user can gain access to images of other customers. Not really recommendable.

Comment: This question wasnt about how to solve the problem and gain the highest security. If so, I'd suggest using encryption bevore saving the value. I could also suggest setting up the lifetime correctly. I even could build up the hole website for him, but that wasnt the question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would upload the image to the folder on a server (user-images), then save the image-path as a $_COOKIE variable (so you can pass it to other files like modify.php or print.php). You'll delete the file with the unlink() function when the session data is no longer available. Something like:

```
if( empty($_SESSION) ){
unlink( $_COOKIE['img_path'] );
setcookie( "img_path", true, time()-10 ); // set negative expire time in order to destroy the cookie
}
```